# Is there any different selenium element to select for Password field?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the login process in https://www.makemytrip.com website. I could able to select the username by id and can pass the keys but the problem is with the password field.

Below is the element i used for password

```
usr = driver.find_element_by_id('password') 
usr.send_keys('****')
```

Also tried with xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
```

But the error message is unable to locate element id password

Below is the html element

```
<input autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" type="password" class="font14" id="password" placeholder="minimum 6 characters." data-cy="password" value="">
```

I have tried many selectors. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: There isn't a password field on that page.

Comment: click on continue and use explicit wait like this `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(password));` and click on `password` webelement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully send keys to the password field using this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# wait for username
username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='username']")))

username_input.send_keys("christine@gmail.com")

# wait on continue button
continue_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//button[span[text()='Continue']]")))

# click continue with Javascript -- button is flakey sometimes
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", continue_button)

# wait for password
password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']")))

password_input.send_keys("testtest")
```

I added a `wait` on the password field. I ran this code in my own Python environment with success.

Comment: Glad to help. Issue for me was the Continue button -- sometimes it did not always  get enabled after entering the username field, so code would not always continue to password field. Javascript click on Continue button solved the underlying issue for me.

Comment: Can i know how exactly that password comment works here? I am new to the Selenium

Comment: Using WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions packages from Selenium, we can tell driver to wait for an element to exist before doing anything with it. This is called explicit wait -- the `.until` method returns the element that is found after waiting for it -- so waiting on `password` web element will also return that element, which is how I got `password_input` variable. It is similar to `driver.find_element`, but instead we are waiting and then finding element, all in one line. Does this make more sense?

Comment: This guide was very useful in helping me understand explicit waits in Python: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will have a look on the  guide